# Do you know any switches which turns on/off based on day light?

Tags: electrical, lighting, wiring, switch

I am looking for having some sensor based switches which will turn on/off the lights based on the light conditions during the day (i.e. turn on when there is less light and turn off when there is more light)

Also, is there a way to connect this switch with multiple light source?

Please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to control the light based on inside or outside levels? Is the light inside or outside? Do you need actual light, or would a celestial timer work (knows what time it gets dark based on your location and day of year)? I have a celestial timer on my front porch light that works great -- turns on at dusk, and off at 11pm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just looking at light switches last night at Home Depot.  There's enough options to make your head spin.

Photosensitive light switches are mainly used for outdoor applications, but some look like they should do fine indoors if oriented properly.

[Automatic Dusk to Dawn Light Control](http://www.shopoutdoorlighting.com/ol21995.htm) - Screws into a light socket

[Photocell Light Control Indoor Plug-in](http://www.pegasuslighting.com/photocell-light-control-indoor-plug-in.html) - Plugs into an outlet

Answer (score 3):

Lutron has a line called Maestro Wireless that has a wireless daylight sensor.

First you would have to have a Maestro Wireless switch or dimmer to match your light source.  Then you can program the sensor to be recognized by the switch/dimmer. If I understand your question about multiple light sources, for each light source you might have a separate switch or dimmer for each source.  Some sources switched on the same switch can be used, like low voltage and regular incandescent on the same (lv or elv) switch. Linear fluorescent would have to have either switches or Lutron ballast that match the system but would dim with readings from the daylight sensor.

You can use the same daylight sensor with different switches or dimmers.  You can also use occupancy sensors inline with the daylight sensor.  The picture below should explain more.

[image: Line card]

[Click here for full size picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydI32.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

By using [light dependent resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) & [Triac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC) circuit, you can Turn on/Off appliances depending on intensity of light.